# JavaScript to parse JSON returned by mongodb aggregate

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I am not sure if there is already a similar question asked but i cant get it to find while searching for a while now. I am using a PHP-Mongodb Aggregate that returns a json as follows ..

```
{"result":[{"_id":{"$id":"52fe557edf80a7a916b68612"},"numComments":3},{"_id":    {"$id":"52dbabb34d4a130c43e6d12c"},"numComments":1}],"ok":1}
```

This is the aggregate i am using ..

```
$result = $collection->aggregate(array(
                    array( '$match' => array( 'hide' => 0 )),
                    array('$unwind' => '$comments'),
                    array( '$group' => array( "_id" => '$_id',
                             'numComments' => array( '$sum' => 1)  ,
                            )
                        ),
                    array( '$sort' => array ( "numComments" => -1 )),
                    array('$limit' => 2)
                )
            );        

  echo json_encode($result);
```

I am unable to get the output (as given earlier) parsed through my javascript to just return the $id and numComments value. I tried looping them through couple of $.each but i always get them as undefined, guess i am close but cant crack as yet.

Any pointers on what i am missing ? some reference to my code that i am trying to use ..

```
 ...
  results1 = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(results));
  results2 = JSON.stringify(results);
  var array = JSON.parse(results1);


        $.each(results1, function(i,item){  

           console.log("item-result : " + item.i); 

              $.each(item.i, function(eventID,eventData) {       

                  $.each(eventData.$id, function(eventID1,eventData1) {       

                 console.log("item-result-NumComments : " + eventData1.numComments);    
                  });

              });

            });

....
```

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE ** How do i make the Mongo to return another field "name" in the aggregate along with "$id" and numComments  ?

**SOLUTION** This is how it can be done using Mongo. $addToSet helps to include more fields.

```
db.records.aggregate( 
{ $match : { 'hide' : 0 } } ,   
{ $unwind : '$comments'},{$project :  { name : '$name', pic1 : '$pic1' } } , 
{ $group : {  _id : '$_id',numComments: { $sum : 1 } , name: { $addToSet : "$name" }    }},  
{ $sort : { 'numComments' : -1} } , 
{ $limit : 5 })
```

Comment: I modified my question now. I got the answer for my earlier question from tymeJV. thanks. How do i get to include another DB field "name" along with $id ?

Comment: I found the mongodb aggregate solution , updated my question here. it may be helpful for someone looking for it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your response `data` parsed, you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.result[i]._id["$id"]);
    console.log(data.result[i].numComments);
}
```

If you're using jQuery's AJAX the response should already be parsed (assuming you specified the type in the call)

Comment: works beautifully. thanks. But, is this how we must do ? And does it have any performance implications in handling the parsed results ?

Comment: @Param -- This is the easiest way, you're response is an object containing an array of objects, so a `for` loop is the way to go. There shouldn't be any performance implications.

Comment: thank you tymeJV. How do in make the Mongo to return one more field "name" along with $id and numComments ?

Comment: Not sure, still learning Mongo, will probably have to ask another question.